# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig since 6.0.0

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro

im working on a flink (v.1.13.2) application which should publish some objects to my Kafka broker.
For schema validation I use the Confluent Schema Registry.

I previously used the library in version 5.2.0 (also tried other 5.x.x versions):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <!--<version>5.x.x</version>--> 
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This seems to work but there was a strange behaviour while registering the schema to the registry. The schema was just ""bytes"" After investigation I found out that the suspect part in 'AvroSchemaUtils' was changed.

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/a2f80f30d6713c50ee54c47885bcde2945932660/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/avro/AvroSchemaUtils.java#L88

So I've tryed to update the library to the next working version.
After I updated to 6.x.x. I've got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:369)
    ... 23 more
```

How to find out what wrong here?

Comment: It would be useful if you shared the Flink code that produces the messages. If the Flink schema was bytes _before serialization_, then that is what will be registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the problem. After Kafka Avro Serializer is upgraded, the dependent kafka client is upgraded from kafka_2.12 to kafka_2.13
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-avro-serializer/6.2.0